# Is there a way to programmatically change the default logging level of the log crate?

Tags: logging, environment-variables, rust

I'm developing a project in Rust that is meant to be used by systems administrators, via CLI.
In this program, I would like to have lines like these:

```
warn!("File {} not found, proceeding to next file", file_path);
```

Which I don't consider errors in the context of the software, but I still would want my users to be aware of.

However, Rust's logging system, by default, only prints messages on the `ERROR` log level, and the only way I found to change this default is to set the `RUST_LOG` environment variable - which I don't want my users to have to do. I guess I could create a wrapper script that just sets the variable and `exec`s the program, but I would rather not.

Is there a way to change the default level programmatically, from inside the program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Just skimming through the code of [`liblog`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/liblog/lib.rs) library you can see that all log level configuration is stored in global variables which are modified only once, using `Once` primitive, and there is no way to modify this configuration.

Rust logging is very simple; if you want something more sophisticated, you will have to do it yourself. `liblog` provides an extension point, a trait called [`Logger`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/log/trait.Logger.html), it probably can be used for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks! This is the correct answer, but I ended up finding a hacky way to do it (see my answer). I still think Rust should allow this to be done though :) (maybe via `--cfg`?)

Answer (score 12):

Here's a trick which will make it

```
if env::var("RUST_LOG").is_err() {
    env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "info")
}
env_logger::init();
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use env_logger you can do in main something like this:

```
    env_logger::builder()
        .filter_level(log::LevelFilter::Debug)
        .format_target(false)
        .format_timestamp(None)
        .init();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an [example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/log/log/index.html#logger-implementations) of what I think you are looking for:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
use log::{LogRecord, LogLevel, LogMetadata, LogLevelFilter, SetLoggerError};

struct SimpleLogger;

impl log::Log for SimpleLogger {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &LogMetadata) -> bool {
        metadata.level() <= LogLevel::Warn
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &LogRecord) {
        if self.enabled(record.metadata()) {
            // I can probably change colors here
            println!("{} - {}", record.level(), record.args());
        }
    }
}

pub fn init() -> Result<(), SetLoggerError> {
    log::set_logger(|max_log_level| {
        max_log_level.set(LogLevelFilter::Warn);
        Box::new(SimpleLogger)
    })
}

fn main() {

    init(); // probably should do something better here

    info!("I am info");
    warn!("I am warn");
    error!("I am error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Vladimir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26143479/667984), I dug on the `liblog` source, and ended up finding a hacky (and probably racy) way to do it:

```
fn main() {
    use std::os;
    os::setenv("RUST_LOG", "warn");
}
```

If this is done before any logging, then the logging system will be set up as if it was set from the outside.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking: 
std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "info");